# Angular2: why is additional fetching necessary after http rest call?

Tags: json, http, angular

I modified the heroes tutorial and I am calling a real http server with a rest api instead of the mock service used in the tutorial.

The rest api returns the following payload:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "comment": "hackathon"
  }
]
```

The code within my service class for getting the heroes looks like that and works perfectly:

```
  getHeroes():Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data)
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Within my adapted class that calls a real http service, I have to use the following code so that it works (e.g. my list contains the payload items).

```
  getItems():Promise<Item[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        response.json().forEach(item => {
          this.entries.push(item);
        });
        return this.entries;
      })
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

It's not clear to me why I have to use the following workaround:

```
    response.json().forEach(item => {
      this.entries.push(item);
    });
    return this.entries;
```

Instead of just using the same code as in the heroes tutorial with the mock server. If I use the part from the heroes tutorial, the result is an empty list of entries.

Comment: Why do you think you have to use this workaround? I think removing `.data` from the `getHeroes()` code should get you the same result.

Comment: `.then(response => response.json())` should be enough, you don't need forEach.

Answer (score 0):

In your service class you can use this method:

```
getItems():Promise<Item[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.url)
   .toPromise()
   .then(response => response.json().data)
   .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

And in your component where uses this service class you do for example:

```
// import your service class...
// import OnInit...

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  entries: any[];

  constructor(private service: Service){}

  ngOnInit() {
   this.service.getItems().then(
    entries => this.entries = entries
   )
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the result is undefined within my AppComponent class if I log this.entries after the assignment.

Comment: What you get if you remove .data from response.json() ?